# How to setup Custom Dimensions using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Can anyone help me to setup custom dimensions using Google Tag manager? I want to track: CustomerID, Userrole, Position.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm only commenting because of OP's name. MarkyMark! Anyway, fraid to say that this isn't related to coding so it's off topic. However, you should be able to Google how do get CD's into GTM.

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed instruction in official documentation:
 https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164990?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/) from Simo Ahava's blog might be helpful. It shows how to implement UserID and ClientID via custom dimensions, so you can borrow the method and fit it to your needs.